# Which is correct: "What kind of CDs" or "What kinds of CDs"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Is it correct to say:

> What kind of CDs do you have?

or

> What kinds of CDs do you have?

Answer (score 13):

I would say **it depends on if you're anticipating a singular or plural answer**.

If you're asking if someone has read-write or read-only CDs, *what kind* would be a sensible question.

If you're curious about the various genres the person has in their music collection, *what kinds* is a better question to ask.

Comment: Though I agree with your explanation, your sentence structure bothers me.  **"I would say it depends on if you're anticipating a singular or plural answer."** Is the usage of *if* proper here ?

Comment: @nsksp - I don't know about 'proper' but it is certainly sounds normal to me.  I guess "whether" might be more formal?