# "These sort of things": is it grammatical? (2,670,000 hits on Google)

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, grammatical-number, agreement

I was interested in the following sentence which appeared in an article titled “[Colorless, Tasteless but Not Dangerous](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/16/books/16book.html)" by Dwight Garner in The New York Times (November 15, 2010).

> People who do gravitate toward *these sort of things*, he warns, sotto
>   voce, might be “the wrong kind of white person.”

Can someone clarify if the fragment "these sort of things" is ungrammatical, as I think it is?

I would reword "sort" with "sorts", but I'm not sure on this correction because the phrase "these sort of things" occurs on many occasions on The New York Times, it frequently occurs in others newspapers and, more generally, it has 2,670,000 hits on Google Search. So I am wondering if it is in common usage, albeit it isn't the highest register.

Comment: Related: [Types of things vs. types of thing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/types-of-things-vs-types-of-thing)¦¦[“This kind of things” vs “These kinds of thing”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68599/this-kind-of-things-vs-these-kinds-of-thing)

Comment: Except that it's not an exact duplicate. This question deals with "these kind of X", with a plural determinant and a singular word from kind/type/sort, and those questions deal with "this kind" or "these kinds".

Comment: Thank you @PeterShor. You have perfectly classified the question. Fortunately, Adam had posted his answer before that the question was being closed.

Comment: This is decidedly **not** a duplicate of the question it’s been marked as a duplicate of. It’s a completely different question, and none of the answers in the dupe (or the related questions in Matt’s comment) address this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP does not understand what Google is saying.

Comment: "these sort of things" only has 396,000 hits on Google -- pretty much noise level.

Comment: @HotLicks much less: see [Page 24 of 236 results](https://www.google.it/search?q=these+sort+of+things&oq=these+sort+of+things&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22these+sort+of+things%22&start=230) (Google.it) and [Page 49 of about 475 results](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22these+sort+of+things%22&start=474) Google.co.uk. I for one do not understand how Google can give such different results.

Comment: This question is nearly 5 years old. I imagine Google's algorithms have changed quite a lot in that time period.

Comment: @MartinSmith from two million hits? I propose that the OP did not close the expression in quotes when he searched Google, it's a common enough error. Hot Licks probably did the same error, when he claimed there were 396,000 hits.

Comment: @Martin Smith: The error with the search estimate is a very old one, I remember encountering it years ago when only starting with English and Japanese. When trying to estimate the use frequency with Google, one must ALWAYS go to the next page and then set the *start* parameter in the search URL to something absurdly high, *that* will show you the real number of pages and hits.

Comment: @Mari-LouA on your UK link if you "repeat the search with the omitted results included." you get 392K which is quite close to what Hot Licks states.

Comment: This all said, Google expects you to lick on something in the first few pages, they don't expect you to go every single mention of your search result on the Internet, so the number of pages does not necessarily reflect the real use frequency. Rather than counting uses, what seems more meaningful is to see whether the websites mentioning the phrase are reputable or not. Also, Google does have the [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/) for the purpose of such frequency inquiries, but it doesn't work very well with modernisms and casual speech as it bases its results on printed books.

Comment: @MartinSmith: With "all results included" you only get [290 results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22these+sort+of+things%22&start=286&filter=0).

Comment: @vovick this is what I see if I go to Mari Lou's UK Link and click the link to include all results https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAOGS.png though if I manually edit the URL to try and see anything past 1,000 it tells me that 1,000 is the max for any query https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22these+sort+of+things%22&rlz=1C9BKJA_enGB590GB590&oq=%22these+sort+of+things%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3314j0j4&hl=en-GB&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#q=%22these+sort+of+things%22&hl=en-GB&start=390000

Comment: @MartinSmith ... then if you click on the pages listed at the bottom you reach [*Page 30 of 297 results*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22these+sort+of+things%22&start=288&filter=0) on Google.co.uk. We're not even close to 1,000 results. Yet the title brags 2 million hits on Google. It aint so :)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Please try clicking "next" or altering the "start" parameter in the URL. You'll run out of pages before reaching 300 results (i.e. page 31).

Comment: @mari-lou AAA whatever are the numbers now in 2017, Peter Shor said 'it's still in use in various regions (mostly in the U.K., I believe) and to people from those regions it sounds perfectly natural'

Comment: @ElberichSchneider the statistic is misleading, it is false, I would delete that number in the title, and show the hits using [Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22these+sort+of+things%22). Again the results seem to be wildly optimist, but at least the citations are legitimate. The question can stand on its own legs.

Comment: @mari-lou AAA I started a bounty just now. Try an answer!

Comment: *“These sort of things”: is it grammatical? (2,670,000 hits on Google)* There are not *2,670,000 hits on Google*. You need to go to the last page of the results, which will tell you ***In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 174 already displayed.***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To gauge the relative popularity of "these sort of things" in historical usage, I ran Elephind newspaper database searches for that phrase and for fifteen related expressions, representing various permutations of *this/these*, *sort/sorts*, and *thing/things* across the period 1800–2017.

---

***Interruption: An important note on Elephind searches***

Before discussing the results, I should observe three things about Elephind search results.

First, the results tend to tend to yield results whose numbers distribute across a bell curve, owing to a couple of factors: (1) the relative scarcity of newspapers in the databases that Elephind searches as you go back in time; and (2) the consequences of copyright restrictions on the availability of newspapers for searches as you come nearer the present. The net result of these contrary forces is that the number of newspapers searched reaches its maximum in the decade 1910–1919, and in fact peaks in 1915. (I base this conclusion on the [results of an Elephind search I ran for the word *the*](http://www.elephind.com/?a=q&r=1&results=1&deq=191&e=-------en-10--1-byDA-txt-txINtxCO-the---------).)

Second, Elephind searches substantially more newspapers from Australia than from the United States over the full range of its coverage (1780–2017). My search for *the*, for example, yielded matches from 104,628,361 Australian newspapers and 42,601,972 U.S. newspapers. That's a lot of newspapers from each country, but it's a lot more from Australia. This reflects the greater accessibility of the digitized newspaper collection through Trove (the online presence of the National Library of Australia) than of the combined Library of Congress and state online newspaper collections in the United States.

Third, newspapers from Australia form an even greater majority of the searchable newspapers from 1925 forward: 47.3 million from Australia to 10.3 million from the United States, judging from my *the* search. That's because Australian newspapers continue to be available from Trove after 1925, whereas the Library of Congress's collection from 1925 forward is not searchable at all. The main sources for U.S. newspapers from the post-1924 era are the state collections from California (3.6 million newspapers), Illinois (2.6 million), Colorado (1.0 million), and Texas (0.79 million).

So the results of an Elephind search give outsize prominence to results from Australia and from states that have searchable newspaper databases (in addition to the states already named, Pennsylvania and Virginia have searchable collections of more than 100,000 newspapers from 1925 onward; and university libraries in Missouri, New York, Ohio, Massachusetts, and Virginia do, too), and they become progressively weaker as you get closer to the present.

Having clarified what the source of my results is, I return to those results.

---

***How usage is distributed in the Elephind results***

Here is the distribution of the matches I got for the sixteen phrases that I searched for across the years 1800–2017 (with the source of the matches further identified in parentheses by country of publication):

> **this sort of thing**:  90,278 newspaper articles (Australia 60,017, United States 30,261)
>
> **thing of this sort**: 1,834 newspaper articles (Australia 1027, United States 807)
>
> **things of this sort**: 1,557 newspaper articles (Australia 641, United States 916)
>
> **these sort of things**: 1,437 newspaper articles (Australia 1,211, United States 226)
>
> **this sort of things**: 331 newspaper articles (Australia 192, United States 139)
>
> **these sorts of things**: 203 newspaper articles (Australia 142, United States 61)
>
> **these sort of thing**: 23 newspaper articles (Australia 17, United States 6)
>
> **these sorts of thing**: 1 newspaper article (Australia 1, United States 0)
>
> **things of these sorts**: 1 newspaper article (Australia 1, United States 0)
>
> **this sorts of thing**: 1 newspaper article (Australia 1, United States 0)
>
> **this sorts of things**: 1 newspaper article (Australia 0, United States 1)
>
> **thing of these sort**: none
>
> **thing of these sorts**: none
>
> **things of these sort**: none
>
> **thing of this sorts**: none
>
> **things of this sorts**: none

Clearly the dominant phrasing is "this sort of thing" at 90,278 matches, a figure that dwarfs two forms that I have heard used quite often and that (I believe) no one would be inclined to challenge as ungrammatical: "thing of this sort" (1,834) newspapers and "things of this sort" (1,557).

But then—to my surprise—comes the wording that the poster asks about—"these sort of things," at 1,437 matches. That number is not tremendously smaller than the numbers for "thing of this sort" and "things of this sort," and it leads me to believe that it is a (or was) a fairly common form of the expression in at least some part of the English-speaking world.

The most noticeable thing about the expression is how strongly the matches skew toward Australian sources: the ratio of Australian to U.S. sources is more than 5 to 1, as against slightly less than 3 to 1 for "thing of this sort," a bit more than 2 to 1 for "thing of this sort," and less than 1 to 1 for "things of this sort."

This last ratio is especially surprising, since one might expect that "this sort of things" might make a natural pairing with "things of this sort." But U.S. usage seems to accept "things of this sort" far more readily than it does "this sort of things."

---

***Conclusion: Is 'these sort of things' grammatical?***

If the test of grammaticality is usage, the Elephind search results tabulated above offer "these sort of things" some fairly impressive credentials for claiming legitimacy—at least in Australia, where, by a very thin margin, it is the second most common form in historical newspaper database occurrences after "this sort of thing." In the Elephind results from the United States, however, it finishes a less impressive fourth, and out-tallies the fifth-place "this sort of things" by a count of only 226 to 139.

As a practical matter, "this sort of thing" is the runaway winner in historical newspaper use in Australia and the United States. Both "thing of this sort" and "things of this sort" seem to pass the no-one-bats-an-eye test as well (at least, I've never heard anything said against them), and that may be true of "these sort of things" in Australian usage, too. But in the United States, "these sort of things" is infrequent enough to prompt some degree of eye batting and perhaps even eyebrow raising when encountered unexpectedly.

Comment: +1 I've noticed quite a few typos in the Washington Post in the last year or so -- not typos that can be blamed directly on Spellchecker -- but typos  that mean the paper is saving $$ on proof-reading, so an indirect result of Spellchecker.  I can't remember an example, but they are irritating.

Comment: But... *is 'these sort of things' grammatical?* - I wanted a simple yes-or-no answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, Sven. Essentially, what I wanted to know is whether I could use that expression in an email. Your answer is elaborate and detailed, but the "Conclusion" section is, in fact, inconclusive... hence my comment. The quoted text is excessively long and formal... It could be simplified and more "to the point", IMHO.

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the grammar norms suggest that the correct usage would be *sorts*. However, after looking into the issue more, I was not so convinced. http://www.phras.in had a high instance rate for *"These sort of things..."* and even Swan's Practical English Usage had an interesting passage about *sort of*:

> When we are talking about one sort of thing, we can use sort of, kind of or type of followed by a singular noun.
>
> *This sort of car is enormously expensive to run.*
>
> Plural demonstratives (these and those) can also be used.
>
> ***These sort of cars are enormously expensive to run. Do you smoke those kind of cigarettes?***
>
> This structure is often felt to be incorrect, and is usually avoided in a formal style. This
> can be done by using a singular noun (see above), by using plural sorts/ kinds/ types, or by
> using the structure ... of this/that sort/kind/type.
>
> This sort of car is ...
> These kinds of car(s) are. . . Cars of that type are ...

Given this, I would say that at least according to Swan and the current usage on the internet at least, both are correct.

Answer (score 8):

As you suspected, the statement is incorrect. *These sorts of things* is correct, because *these* is used to refer to plural nouns. *This sort of thing* is also correct; it is singular. However, *These sort of thing* has *these* being used to refer to the singular *sort*, and so it is wrong.

Comment: When you get 2.5 million hits on Google, I would posit that brandishing a particular usage as "incorrect" is overly simplistic.

Comment: @Neil Coffrey: Slang is commonly accepted as part of the language, but it's still "incorrect" in a grammatical sense. If a grammar is a set of rules it really gets to be a pain if you need to incorporate every slang phrase as an exception to the rule!

Comment: I'm still confused: why don't you take the 2.5 million hits as a possible indication that the usage may not actually be considered "incorrect" (and may not actually be considered "slang") by many writers? Or another way to see things: what actual data/survey of writers etc are you basing your answer on?

Comment: How long do people have to have been using these sort of expressions before they stop being incorrect? [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thefe+fort+of%2Cthefe+kind+of%2Cthefe+forts+of%2Cthefe+kinds+of&year_start=1600&year_end=1850&corpus=0&smoothing=40) shows they go back to the 17th century, when *these sort of* and *these kind of* were more common than *these sorts of* and *these kinds of*.

Comment: It isn't incorrect because it violates a grammatical rule, as exceptions to those are common. Its incorrect because it still sounds awkward to the modern ear. If it stops sounding awkward and wrong,  then it stops being awkward and wrong.

Comment: Actually, saying that _these sort of_ was more common is very interesting. Maybe it used to be perfectly natural. It just sounds wrong now. Given that those were more common, _archaic_ may well be more accurate than _incorrect_.

Comment: Except that it's still in use in various regions (mostly in the U.K., I believe) and to people from those regions it sounds perfectly natural.

Comment: @NeilCoffey - **YOU DO NOT GET 2.5 MILLION HITS ON GOOGLE.**

Comment: "It isn't incorrect because it violates a grammatical rule, as exceptions to those are common. It[']s incorrect because it still sounds awkward to the modern ear. If it stops sounding awkward and wrong, then it stops being awkward and wrong." Certainly. But as @tchrist has said: "We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers."

Answer (score 8):

Both **'this sort of thing is...** ' and **'these sorts of things are...'** are in use, the latter being less common and informal.

From **Michael Swan's Practical English Usage**:

> ### sort of, kind of and type of
>
> #### articles
>
> The article *a/an* is usually dropped after *sort of, kind of* and *type of*, but structures with articles are possible in an informal style.
>
> - That's a funny **sort of (a)** car.
> - What **sort of (a)** bird is that?
>
> #### singular and plural; these sort of etc
>
> When we are talking about one sort of thing, we can use *sort of, kind of* or *type of* followed by a singular noun.
>
> - This **sort of car** is enormously expensive to run.
> - I'm interested in any new **type of development** in computer science.
>
> Singular *sort of, kind of* and *type of* can also be followed by plural nouns, especially in an informal style.
>
> - I'm interested in any new **kind of developments**…
>
> Plural demonstratives (*these* and *those*) can also be used.
>
> - **These sort of cars** are enormously expensive to run.
> - Do you smoke **those kind of cigarettes**?
>
> This structure is often felt to be incorrect, and is usually avoided in a formal style. This can be done by using a singular noun (see above), by using plural *sorts/kinds/types*, or by using the structure… *of this/that sort/kind/type*.
>
> - **This sort of car** is…
> - **These kinds of car(s)** are…
> - **Cars of that type** are…

Also, from **The New Fowler's Modern English Usage** [with minor adjustments]:

> (2) **these/those sort of**: From C16 onward, *sort* has been used
> collectively, preceded (illogically) be *these* or *those*. For
> example
>
> - ***Inchoatives** ... are those sort of Verbs which express a gradual proceeding in any action* [E Phillips 1671]
> - *"Those sort of rules are all gone by now," said Mr. Arabin* [Trollope 1857]
> - *These sort of people are only interested in lining their pockets* [J Leland 1987]
>
> Not unexpectedly, the plural form **these/those sorts of** is also
> used:
>
> - *He ... did an infinity of those sorts of things which were not professionally required of him* [T Hook 1825]
> - *To afford her apartment in New York, she often took these sorts of library fellowships* ['New Yorker' 1989]
>
> The type **these/those sort of** should now be used only in informal
> contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The argument that you get 2.5 million hits on Google, or some other enormous number, is wrong.  The expression is really quite rare.

When I Google with `these sort of things`, with no quotes around the argument, I get an estimated 230 million hits.  But if I "Next" to the end of the list of "unique" hits, I get only 234 hits.  Doing "repeat search with omitted results" it estimates 307 million hits, but lists only 322 if you "Next" to the end.  Keep in mind that this list of hits includes web pages that contain the four words in any order and interspersed with other words, not contiguous in the order specified.

When I Google with `"these sort of things"` (quotes included), I get an estimated 396,000 hits.  "Nexting" to the end, Google lists only 249 hits.  If I "repeat search with the omitted results included" I still get an estimated 396,000 hits, but "Next" gives up on page 63 (ie, about 640 hits) without claiming to be at the end.

Googling `"these sorts of things"` (note the plural), I get an estimated 477,000 hits, and "Nexting" to the end it gives up with 255 results.  Doing "repeat search with omitted results", it still estimates 477,000 hits, then refuses to search any farther after "Next" counts 300 results.

If I Google for the expression `"the first thing that"`, Google estimates 35,500,000 hits and, with "omitted results", actually lists 324.

It's hard to interpret these results, other than to say that:

1. Google "estimates" are probably "over-estimates", while the actual number of entries returned is almost certainly an undercount, with a number in the neighborhood of 200-300 being likely.  (I don't know if the one outlier has any significance or is just a random oddity.)
2. If you don't include quotes around a phrase when you Google it, the numbers are entirely meaningless, but if you include the quotes then the "estimates" *probably* can be roughly compared to estimate frequency.

Comment: And I'll note that if you look at [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=these+sort+of+things%2C+these+sorts+of+things&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthese%20sort%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20sorts%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0) you will see that "sort" was oddly more popular than sorts" until about 1970.

Answer (score 1):

The only grammatically acceptable forms are obviously: this sort of thing, this sort of things, these sorts of thing and these sorts of things. To write: "these sort" or "this sorts" are grammatical fallacies.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the accepted answer as an example of the level of detail we expect from a good answer here.

Comment: You should expand to explain why your answer is correct: it is a simple case of the demonstrative adjective agreeing with its noun rather than the noun's modifier.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to [The Grammar of English Grammars, 10th edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=e2lOAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA545&dq=%22these%20sort%20of%20things%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj75_A6qPSAhUKRCYKHYhmDxYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22these%20sort%20of%20things%22&f=false) (1869)

On pages 544-545, under the title "Improprieties For Correction: False Syntax Under Rule IX: Examples under note I.-Agreement of Adjectives" there is the example:

> "For these sort of things are usually join'd to the most noted fortune" *Bacon's Essays* page 101.