# Which is correct: kind or kinds?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

The shopkeeper had hardly any of those kind/kinds of goods.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["This kind of things" vs "These kinds of thing"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68599/this-kind-of-things-vs-these-kinds-of-thing)

Answer (score 1):

In American English, "kinds" is correct because "those" goes with a plural. From what I've seen, British English would be more likely to use "those kind," taking into consideration that "kind" refers to a group even though it isn't plural itself.

Answer (score 1):

'Kinds' is definitely the correct choice here. I don't know which specific kind of English speaker would use 'kind', because 'goods' indicates or implicates various objects. Never forget to pluralize.

You would only use 'kind' if one were trying to refer to one specific object. In that case, a sentence would be formed using '*that kind* of good'. Here, you most definitely are required to opt for 'those **kinds** of goods'.

Comment: Small correction: it should be "*that kind of goods*".