# How many kinds are one?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, quantifiers

Is "kind", as a noun, singular, or plural? People nearly always say "these/those kind of (things)" rather than "this/that kind of (things)" makes more sense.

Comment: Related and probable duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68599.

Comment: I'm more used to hearing 'this kind of thing' or 'these kinds of things'.

Comment: Is it meant to be "these kind of things" in the question, or was that a typo for "these kinds of things"?

Comment: @tchrist: Your link is potentially a duplicate of the one I marked.

Comment: @Robusto, tchrist: I found and linked to the earlier *kind/kinds* question before noticing your two, simply because it was *exactly* focussed on the specific word used here. But looking at them both now, I agree Robusto's one covers the general case much better, so I'm off to CV the other one (even though I've just cited it as the "original" duplicate for this one).