# This kind of or these kind of

Tags: grammar, pronouns

1. I like *this* kind of foods.

Or

2. I like *these* kind of foods.

Which pronoun is correct here?

Comment: Neither. You have the make the numbers agree: *This kind of food* or *These kinds of foods*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This kind of things" vs "These kinds of thing"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68599/this-kind-of-things-vs-these-kinds-of-thing) / 'These kind of things' is also addressed; apparently, this wrong-looking usage has a long history dating back to Shakespeare.